# Hibernate mapping non-entity classes. org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql, hibernate-mapping, entitymanager

I have a table `[order_id, guest_id, maintenance_id, order_timestamp]`, and I want to select list of `timestamps`, when the `guest_id` ordered `maintenance_id`.

I simply tried to select `LocalDateTime` with the code below, but hibernate threw:
`Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.time.LocalDateTime`

```
    public List<LocalDateTime> getGuest2MaintenanceOrderTime(long guestId, long maintenanceId) {
        List<?> resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM guest_2_maintenance where guest_id = ? and maintenance_id = ?", LocalDateTime.class)
                .setParameter(1, guestId)
                .setParameter(2, maintenanceId)
                .getResultList();
        return (List<LocalDateTime>) resultList;
```

It seems strange to me to create separate class for holding date, and annotate it with `@Entity`. How to select `LocalDateTime` and map it to a new `LocalDateTime` object?

Mapping `LocalDateTime` as field of `@Entity` object works fine, but in my case this table field does not belong to any `@Entity`

Comment: If you are not using an `Entity` class, then why do you need to use Hibernate to do this? Simply use plain JDBC to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you do 'select * ...'
There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Select only time field

   ```
           List<LocalDateTime> resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                           "SELECT order_timestamp FROM guest_2_maintenance where guest_id = ? and maintenance_id = ?", LocalDateTime.class)
                   .setParameter(1, guestId)
                   .setParameter(2, maintenanceId)
                   .getResultList();
           return resultList;
   }
   ```
2. Or you should use an entity and then retrieve order_timestamp field from it. [For example](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3373652/java-persistence-with-jpa-and-hibernate-part-1-entities-and-relationships.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akortex and @Human Bean for responsing but I managed to make it works somehow this way:

```
public List<LocalDateTime> getGuest2MaintenanceOrderTime(long guestId, long maintenanceId) {
    List<Timestamp> resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                    "SELECT order_timestamp FROM guest_2_maintenance where guest_id = ? and maintenance_id = ?")
            .setParameter(1, guestId)
            .setParameter(2, maintenanceId)
            .getResultList();
    List<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeList = new ArrayList<>();
    resultList.forEach(timestamp -> {
        localDateTimeList.add(timestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    });
    return localDateTimeList;
}
```